# Al insertar numero en input actualizar los otros dos sin tener que cambiar de input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, entrada

como decia en la pregunta, estoy actualizando unos inputs a través de lo que inserto en dos de ellos, el de cantidad y el del precio unidad. Ahora me esta actualizando bien con AJAX, pero necesita que cambie de input para que actialice, hay alguna forma de conforme escriba si vaya actualizando instantaneamente??? Saludos

El AJAX

```
      $('#ePrecioUnd, #cntComprada').on("change", function(e) {
         var unidad = $(this).val();
          var precio = $("#ePrecioUnd").val();
          var cantidad = $("#cntComprada").val();

           var datos = {
            'precio': precio,
            'cantidad': cantidad,
             };
               $.ajax({
                  url: "sumasFact.php",
                  type: "post",
                  dataType: "json",
                  data: datos,
                  success: function (resultado){
                    $("#eSubTotal").val(resultado.totalConCantidades);
                    $("#iva").val(resultado.ivaD100);
                    $("#eTotal").val(resultado.ivaTotal);
                  }
              });
         console.log(unidad);
        });
```

La Respuesta

```
include ("../conexion/conexion.php");


$cantidad =$_POST['cantidad'];
$precio=$_POST['precio'];
$totalConCantidades = $precio * $cantidad;
$ivaX21 = $totalConCantidades*21;
$ivaD100 = $ivaX21/100;
$ivaTotal = $ivaD100 + $totalConCantidades;

$resultado=array();
  $resultado['totalConCantidades'] =  $totalConCantidades;
  $resultado['ivaD100'] =  $ivaD100;
  $resultado['ivaTotal'] =  $ivaTotal;
echo json_encode($resultado)
```

Y lo inprimo en el input con el #ID

Comment: has mirado eventos como keyup?

Comment: Estupendo, si que era la solución @lois6b

Comment: perfect. Ahora puedes hacer tu mismo una respuesta explicando como cambiar tu código para que funcione. Para futuros usuarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solución con la ayuda de @lois6b

```
// Evento que es lanzado cuando se escribe en un campo. busca así: event when type jquery. =)
      $('.inputcalculo').keyup(function(e) {
         var unidad = $(this).val();
          var precio = $("#ePrecioUnd").val();
          var cantidad = $("#cntComprada").val();
          console.log(precio + " - " + cantidad);
           var datos = {
            'precio': precio,
            'cantidad': cantidad,
             };
               $.ajax({
                  url: "sumasFact.php",
                  type: "post",
                  dataType: "json",
                  data: datos,
                  success: function (resultado){
                    $("#eSubTotal").val(resultado.totalConCantidades);
                    $("#iva").val(resultado.ivaD100);
                    $("#eTotal").val(resultado.ivaTotal);
                  }
              });
         //console.log(unidad);
        });
```

Simplemente añadir evento `keyup`